# File.ReadAllBytes() return {byte[0]}

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I want to uplad file to specific location using asp.net webservice .When I writing this:

```
byte[] file = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
```

and passing webservice,webservice works fine.Client can be windows service may not web application.File path can be sent to service.From file path,I want to convert to byte array.So I used

```
 byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\riya\\Desktop\\sample.txt");
```

But it is not working.Array always contain zero`{byte[0]}`.How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You read the file from disk using `FileStream` and copy it to a `MemoryStream`. Once in memory you can use the file.

```
byte[] bin;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("C:\\Users\\riya\\Desktop\\sample.txt"))
{
    fs.CopyTo(ms);
    bin = ms.ToArray();
}
```